# Derefence pointer to object from vector in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a class that is inserting nodes with these functions:

In Node.h

```
class Node
{
public:
...
void insertChild(Node *child);
vector<Node *> children();
vector<Node *> _children;
};
```

In Node.cpp

```
void Node::insertChild(Node *child){
    _children.push_back(child);
}

vector<Node *> Node::children(){
return _children;
}
```

In Trie.h

```
class Trie
{
public:
Node *getRoot() const;
Node *root;
void addWord(string prefix);
}
```

In Trie.cpp

```
Trie::Trie()
{
root = new Node();
}

Node *Trie::getRoot() const
{
return root;
}

void Trie::addWord(string prefix){
    Node *current = root;

    if(prefix.length() == 0)
    {
        current->setTypeMarker(DAT_NODE);
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < prefix.length(); i++){
        Node *child = current->lookupChild(prefix[i]);
        if(child != NULL)
        {
            current = child;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *tmp = new Node();
            tmp->setContent(prefix[i]);
            current->insertChild(tmp);
            current = tmp;
        }
        if(i == prefix.length()-1)
            current->setTypeMarker(DAT_NODE);
     }
}
```

In another class, I want to iterate over _children so I have

In OtherClass.h

```
class OtherClass
{
public:
Trie *trie;
void addWords(string word)
void someFunction()
}
```

In OtherClass.cpp

```
OtherClass::OtherClass()
{
tree = new Trie();
}

void OtherClass::addWords(string word)
{
tree->addWord(word);
}

void OtherClass::someFunction()
{
Node *root = tree->getRoot();
    for(std::vector<Node *>::iterator it = root->children().begin(); it != root->children().end(); it++) {
        Node * test = *it;
    }
}
```

However, when I run this, test is nil. I can look at root and see that children contains my Nodes, but how come I can't de-reference them in the vector iterator? `children()` is my getter for `_children`

Comment: Note that encapsulation requires more than just defining a private variable.  If that variable is immediately accessible via a public accessor, it isn't encapsulated at all.

Comment: How do you feel about providing the code that *isn't* here? (in this case, likely near-all of it). Or put together an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that reproduces the issue. You said "in another class.." Is that class inheriting from `Trie` ? does it tout around its own `root` object pointer with its own vector of (in this case) nothing?

Comment: "the other class" i was referring to calls a `Trie::getRoot()` function to get the `Node *root`; variable that is public in `Trie`

Comment: And where does that other class instance get its `Trie` instance from?  As-in, the Trie instance that you're invoking `getRoot()` for? (post more code *please*; there isn't enough here to answer your question, though I now have a suspicion).

Comment: I am working on making a reduced example - its too large to post all as is. Basically the "other class" has `Trie *tree` as a private variable.

Comment: And `OtherClass::tree` was set by... do you see where this is going? Your entire question hinges on the premise that the node you're dereferencing and grabbing a `Node* vector reference from is the same one you actually pushed data into. Once we have more code we'll have a better understanding, I'm sure.

Comment: Add your children() getter's code, please.

Comment: I guess its still not clear. *This doesn't reproduce your problem.* And nowhere in here is `OtherClass::tree` ever used to add any children. In fact, its simply set to a `new Trie()` and thats it.

Comment: Sorry, I was still working on adding when Dmitry posted. I added the full addWord code and a call to it

Comment: May as well post `lookupChild()` as well, and note, if *anyone* uses `children()` to get the child vector of a node (including the node itself) and then uses that vector for insertions, its pointless, as you're not modifying the *real* child vector of the node; its a copy. See Dmitry's answer if that is the case.

Comment: Internally to the Node I was always using _children instead of the getter. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your getter return std::vector by value not by the reference?

The getter should look like this:

```
std::vector<Node*>& Node::children()
{
    return _children;
}
```

or for const version like this:

```
const std::vector<Node*>& Node::children() const
{
    return _children;
}
```

Comment: Well I used the non-const getter you have provided and it seems like that works. Can you explain or point me to exactly why that needs to be the case?

Comment: Because when you return the vector by value you get COPY of the _children not the reference to it. So your cycle was from first element of the temporary object created by your getter to end of the another copy.

Comment: Hrmm. I was using an IDE to generate the getters/setters and I just checked and it definitely doesn't return by reference. I will have to beware of this in the future I suppose

Comment: @Derek It matters a great deal if you use `children()` to perform insertions *anywhere*. All you're doing if that is the case is modifying a local vector *copy* and it will be lost as soon as the caller's function exits. If it is only used for value-lookups its ok, but any volatility you express against a vector returned from `children()` as-written will be lost. If that is the case, Mr. Poroh is quite-correct.

Comment: Yes I see that that would cause a problem. I guess I am still unclear as to why the copy gave me zero-valued pointers to the children though. I would have thought I would at least be able to 'read only' using that method as it was written before.

Comment: @Derek the "copy" would give you zero if the original insertion you only-think went into your node vector went into a copy of *it* in the first place. Thats one way.